# The ability to choose SwiftUI and UIKit when creating a project has disappeared

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uikit

Previously, when creating a project, there was a choice between SwiftUI and UIKit. Here's what it looked like before:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwLaN.jpg

And this is what it looks like now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OtEu.png

Thus, any new project is created by default using the SwiftUI template.
Maybe I missed something, and now the creation of a project based on UIKit is happening in some other way? I will be glad of your help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably asked (in the Template Chooser) for a *multiplatform app.* That can only be SwiftUI, by definition, so there's no need for any choice to be presented to you.

[image]

Comment: Hell, yes, you're right. I apologize for the rather stupid question and thank you for taking the time.